# Tiff to Base64String convertion or display Issues

Tags: html, .net, image

Having issues getting a Tiff image I'm receiving from USPS to render into a base64String and then display successfully using an html image tag.

MY guess at this point is either the image is corrupted in some way that dose not allow it to be converted into correct base64. Or, I am missing something when trying to display the image.

I can "successfully" convert the image to a base64String using the base .Net conversion library and several other online converters. No issues from what I can tell there. But when I go to display the image I'm unable to get it to render.

```
<img src="data:image/tiff;base64,{myBase64String}" alt="Return Label Image">
```

The full image source with my base64 string,
https://jsfiddle.net/h8qzn9g0/

The Tiff image in question:
https://kibocommerce-my.sharepoint.com/personal/aaron_jones_kibocommerce_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=J0lu1b8DSkH5Y2AhZoORnXtaBoXS%2bh81%2bDbvePlIgGY%3d&docid=18737654320874e94812de23beb09904f&rev=1

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoding is fine, if I paste it into the box at http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html and hit "Decode and Download" it downloads the image. The fiddle works in Safari, but not other browsers. Main issue is that most browsers don't support TIFF.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

You will need to change to a different image format, maybe PNG or JPG, before you can use the data URI in all browsers.

Comment: You are correct that was the issue. Converting the images to png now and it's working great. Thanks